# How to delete NavigationLink in List

Tags: swift, swipe-gesture, swiftui-navigationlink

I have following code in my project

```
@State private var selectedGenreID: Int64? = 0

@FetchRequest(entity: Genres.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "genName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))])
var genres: FetchedResults<Genres>

var body: some View {
    List(genres, id: \Genres.genID, selection: $selectedGenreID, rowContent: { genre in
        NavigationLink(genre.genName!, destination: GenreView(isNew: false, genre: genre))
    })
    .navigationBarTitle("Žánry")
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: GenreView(isNew: true), label: {Image(systemName: "plus.circle")}))
}
```

and I'm wondering how to implement swipe to delete functionality for each row in the list. I know it should be via .onDelete modifier but I don't know how to apply for List constructed as above. It works if List is created via ForEach.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with using ForEach inside a list? You can only use the .onDelete modifier with ForEach. In your example (a list without ForEach inside) a list with one cell that contains all your nav links, what should be deleted with .onDelete in your case?

Something like this:

```
    List {
        ForEach(genres, id:\Genres.genID) { genre in // here I don't know what your Genres.ID is so could be mistake
            NavigationLink(destination: GenreView(isNew: false, genre: genre)) {
                Text("\(genre.genName!)")
            }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                // save selected id if you need
            })
        }.onDelete(perform: // your onDelete action here)
    }
```

Comment: Hello, ForEach is not an issue at all. Unfortunately .simultaneousGesture closure is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally made it

```
List {
        ForEach(genres, id:\Genres.genID) { genre in
            NavigationLink(destination: GenreView(isNew: false, genre: genre)) {
                Text("\(genre.genName!)")
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: { indexes in
            for index in indexes {
                let genre = genres[index]
                //Handling of deletion
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
var body: some View {
List(genres, id: \Genres.genID, selection: $selectedGenreID, rowContent: { genre in
    NavigationLink(genre.genName!, destination: GenreView(isNew: false, genre: genre))
})
```

fix example:

```
var body: some View {
List {
ForEach(genres, id: \Genres.genID, selection: $selectedGenreID, rowContent: { genre in
    NavigationLink(genre.genName!, destination: GenreView(isNew: false, genre: genre))
})
}
    .onDelete(perform: deleteRow)

func deleteRow(at offsets: IndexSet) {
  ganres.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

just List(... change to ForEach(...